# ssh клиент под андроид

Tags: android, ssh

Подскажите ssh клиент под андроид, которому можно доверить свои пароли.

Answer (score 3):

Например, [ConnectBot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.connectbot&hl=ru). Свободное программное обеспечение.

Дополнительные ссылки:
[Официальный сайт](https://connectbot.org/)
[Исходный код на GitHub'е](https://github.com/connectbot/connectbot/)

Comment: Вот, собственно, такие вопросы и порождают link-only ответы, которые потом попадают в очередь _Сообщения плохого качества_.

Comment: @Regent, вполне нормальный ответ. Уж если google play сдохнет, то вопрос о хорошем приложении под андроид свой смысл очень сильно поменяет...

Comment: @Qwertiy так ведь дело не только в уверенности в стабильности ссылки. И я понимаю, что автору (возможно, и будущем посетителям, если к этому времени указанное приложение не потеряет актуальность) лучше так, чем никак. Но это мы снова возвращаемся к обсуждению с Меты, а я последние несколько дней  не готов к дебатам.

Comment: @Regent, честное слово, не я его задал!

Comment: @Regent, человек ищет хорошее приложение. Открывает ссылку, читает, ставит. Всё хорошо. Ссылка не открывается? Тогда приложения уже нет и поставить его вряд ли получится. Что можно сделать, чтобы улучшить ответ? Скопировать описание? Да кому оно нужно, если приложения нет? А если есть, то и по ссылке прочитать не проблема.

Comment: @Qwertiy у меня ведь претензия к вопросу, а не к ответу. При таком вопросе и описание пользы не принесёт, да. Подобные вопросы на данный момент "вне закона", Принесёт ли пользу ресурсу послабления в этом плане в правилах - не знаю, тут только практика может это показать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо за ценную правку! невзирая на измененённый авторский стиль.

Comment: Возрастной рейтинг 3+ ))

Answer (score 1):

Пользуюсь [JuiceSSH - SSH Client](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh&hl=ru)ом вроде все нормально работает.

Но если есть подозрения что какой то клиент программа ворует пароли, лучше меняйте пароль сервера чаше.

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать [JuiceSSH](https://androidapplications.ru/programs/5447-juicessh-ssh-client.html), из всех возможных *ssh* клиентов самый удобный. Раньше использовал *MobileSSH*, но они более года не вносили никаких обновлений.